# ggplot2 : Bar plot in decreaing/increasing order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with this structure :

```
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Age        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Middle","Old",..: 2 1 3 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Gender     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ OwnHome    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Own","Rent": 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Married    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Married","Single": 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Location   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Close","Far": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Salary     : int  47500 63600 13500 85600 68400 30400 48100 68400 51900 80700 ...
 $ Children   : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ History    : Factor w/ 3 levels "High","Low","Medium": 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 NA ...
 $ Catalogs   : int  6 6 18 18 12 6 12 18 6 18 ...
 $ AmountSpent: int  755 1318 296 2436 1304 495 782 1155 158 3034 ...
```

and want to make a bar plot with `geom_bar()` for `Age`:

```
Age : 
Middle:508
Old   :205
Young :287
```

when I run this code below:

```
age_plt <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Age))
age_plt + geom_bar()
```

I want ggplot to draw the plot in increasing order(first `Old`,second `Young` and the last `Middle`).

How can I add this feature to my code ?(preferably without using any other variables ,because in the next steps I want to add some new features to the same plot(for example grouping the plot with `Gender` column.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the factor order for **Age** before ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
  mutate(Age = fct_relevel(Age,"Old","Young"))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Age)) +
   geom_bar()
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, but I used following code for changing factor order;`age_sort <- as.data.frame(sort(table(df$Age)))
df$Age <- factor(df$Age, levels = age_sort$Var1)`